# How to use the angular material's "Determinate Progress circular" in loading route pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to angularjs, and I want to use the *Angular Material's* Progress Circular spinner in every route changes on my page. In my application, I am using `ng-route` for the link of my pages. I am currently using a gif loader as of now. But I want the progress circular in angular. In the explanation of the `Determinate` it says that:
 `For operations where the percentage of the operation completed can be determined, use a determinate indicator. They give users a quick sense of how long an operation will take.`
Here's my current code:

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){

         $routeProvider
         .when('/',{
              templateUrl: 'home.html',
              controller:  'homeCtrl',
              resolve: {
                    delay: function($q, $timeout){
                            var delay = $q.defer();
                            $timeout(delay.resolve, 1500);
                            return delay.promise;
                    }
              }
         })
         .when('/about',{
              templateUrl: 'about.html',
              controller:  'aboutCtrl',
              resolve: {
                    delay: function($q, $timeout){
                            var delay = $q.defer();
                            $timeout(delay.resolve, 1500);
                            return delay.promise;
                    }
              }
          })
          .otherwise({
                 redirectTo: '/'
          });
 });




  app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope){
        ...
  });
  app.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope){
        ...
  });


 app.directive('showDuringResolve', function($rootScope) {

   return {
     link: function(scope, element) {

       $rootScope.statechange = true;

       var unregister = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {

            $rootScope.statechange = false;

       });

            $scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
     }
   };
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

         <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->

         <div ng-view ng-show="statechange"></div>

         <!-- SHOW THE LAODING GIF EVERY STATE CHANGE -->
         <div ng-show="!statechange" show-during-resolve >
                <img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
         </div>



</div>
```

**USAGE OF PROGRESS CIRCULAR**
**html**

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.determinateValue}}">   </md-progress-circular>
```

**js**

```
angular
  .module('progressCircularDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$interval',
    function($interval) {
      var self = this;

      self.activated = true;
      self.determinateValue = 30;

      // Iterate every 100ms, non-stop and increment
      // the Determinate loader.
      $interval(function() {

       self.determinateValue += 1;
      if (self.determinateValue > 100) {
        self.determinateValue = 30;
       }

      }, 100);
    }
 ]);
```

**That's it!** Now, I want that loader replace by the `ANGULAR MATERIAL'S Progress Circular`. How to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the required dependencies,

```
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/docs.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>
```

inject the required dependencies in your module

```
var app =  angular
  .module('myApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);
```

and add the html for progress bar

```
 <md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.determinateValue}}"></md-progress-circular>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/m2iGSQCxY35Y2zFUNXPL?p=preview

Comment: @Trish Did this help??